# How to show Data from Javascript to form Modal HTML

Tags: javascript, php, html

**I want to ask my problem hehe:** in my case I want to show my data selector from JavaScript to my modal.

From my code, I have done using `console.log()` to view the data and it works, but it still didn't want to show in my form modal. Please help me where i'm missing it hehe ...

### This is my JavaScript

```
<script> 

          let namaToko = document.getElementById("namaToko").innerHTML;
          let alamatToko = document.getElementById("alamatToko").innerHTML;
          let buttonDetail = document.querySelectorAll('.view-detail');
          buttonDetail.forEach(function(_el)  {
            _el.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
              jQuery('#modalUpdate').modal('show');
              let row = document.querySelector(`[data-row-id="${e.target.dataset.id}"]`);
              let nama = row.querySelector('td:nth-child(2)');
              let alamat = row.querySelector('td:nth-child(3)');
              
              console.log(nama);
              console.log(alamat);
              
              namaToko = nama;
              alamatToko = alamat;

            });
          });

      </script>
```

### This is my form modal and the datatable

```
<!-- Bagian Edit Form Modal -->
            <div class="modal fade modalUpdate" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true" id="modalUpdate">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Edit Data Toko</h4>
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                  </button>
                </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                <form method = "post" action = "library/services/formAction.php">
                  <input type="hidden" name="pageReferrer" value="http://localhost/city/?page=store" >
                  <input type="hidden" name="actionObject" value="toko" >
                  <input type="hidden" name="actionType" value="update" >
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="namaToko" class="col-form-label">Nama Toko</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="namaToko" placeholder="Masukkan Nama Toko" name="namaToko" required>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="alamatToko" class="col-form-label">Alamat Toko</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="alamatToko" placeholder="Masukkan Nama Toko" name="alamatToko" required>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit">Save</button>
              </div>
                </form>
              </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Akhir Edit Bagian Modal -->
            

              <!-- /.card-header -->
              <div class="card-body">
                <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                  <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>No</th>
                    <th>Toko</th>
                    <th>Alamat</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <th>Opsi</th>
                  </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                  <?php
                    $n=1;
                    $toko = getDataToko();
                    while ($dataToko = mysqli_fetch_array($toko)) {
                      if($dataToko['status_ot']==1)
                      {
                        $status = "Aktif";
                        $idStatus = "1"; 
                      }
                      if($dataToko['status_ot']==2)
                      {
                        $status = "Tidak Aktif";
                        $idStatus = "2"; 
                      }
                    
                  ?>
                  <tr data-row-id="<?= $dataToko['id_ot'] ?>">
                    <td>
                    <?php echo $n++; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    <?php echo $dataToko['nama_ot'] ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    <?php echo $dataToko['alamat_ot'] ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    <?php echo $status ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    <button type ="button" class ="view-detail btn btn-success" data-id="<?= $dataToko['id_ot'] ?>"> Edit </button>
                    <button type = "button" class = "btn btn-danger deletebtn"> Delete </button>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <?php
                  }
                  ?>   
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </div>
              <!-- /.card-body -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.card -->
          </div>
          <!-- /.col -->
        </div>
```

And this is the picture where i'm click the Edit Button, and the data was showing in the console but didn't show up in my modal form:

[image]

Comment: So you want to show data from `<td>` to form?

Comment: yeahh you 're right

Comment: `let namaToko = document.getElementById("namaToko");
let alamatToko = document.getElementById("alamatToko");

namaToko.value = nama.innerText;
alamatToko.value = alamat.innerText;`

Comment: Am i still need innerHTML on my let namaToko?

Comment: No. Just remove it. You don't need innerHTML. innerHTML gives HTML content from particular tag. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML

Comment: Okeyy done, but still didn't work :(

Comment: Any error in console

Comment: No, but the data can retrieve in console log, but in my modal form cant show up

Comment: It still same hehe

Comment: `jQuery("#modalUpdate #namaToko").val(nama.innerText);
jQuery("#modalUpdate #alamatToko").val(alamat.innerText);`

Comment: Ahhh finally hehehe, its done, thankyouu

Comment: Hey @RidhoWisnu if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.

Comment: Okayy i have done it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[If you give your form a name you can then set its input values using their name.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/forms#named_form_access)

```html
<form name="myForm" method = "post" action = "library/services/formAction.php">
```

```js
const myForm = document.forms.myForm;
myForm.elements.namaToko.value = namaToko;
myForm.elements.alamatToko.value = alamatToko;
```

Answer (score 1):

To set value

```
jQuery("#modalUpdate #namaToko").val(nama.innerText);
jQuery("#modalUpdate #alamatToko").val(alamat.innerText);
```